# How to animate clouds

Tags: unity, sky, skybox, clouds

I am creating an open-world in Unity 4.5.5 and I do not know how to make the clouds move. [This video of The Legend of Zelda: Wind Waker HD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83TERg4RBbQ) is a perfect example of the clouds moving in the sky. How can I create this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Skydome - it's a Unity package that allows for animated skyboxes.

http://www.pixelstudio.nl/?p=138